# PHP Doctrine2 search "Like" with an Array "%$array%"

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine, sql-like

**Doctrine2.5 With PHP 5.6**

I have an array of things to search, example:
in a table of user, i want to search for the names of everyone that have
the name "Reis" or "Shimidt" in the field name. With the array

```
$arraySearch = ['Reis', 'Shimidt'];
```

I want to bring for example the following entries,

- John Reis Carlson,
- Mary Shimidt Lincoln,
- Bill Reis Abdonor Gates.

I tried something like this:

```
$this->query->andWhere(" pb.name LIKE '%:name%' ");
$this->query->setParameter('name', $name, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::SIMPLE_ARRAY);
```

It doesnt work, i also tried like this, but obviously returned array to string conversion:

```
$this->query->setParameter('name', '%'.$name.'%', \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::SIMPLE_ARRAY);
```

Any ideas how to solution this, without to do a messy code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to use something like this:

```
foreach ($arraySearch as $search) {
    $this->query->orWhere(" pb.name LIKE :search ");
    $this->query->setParameter("search", '%'.$search.'%');
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you! Accept the answer to help other persons with your same problem @AlbertAbdonor

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$this->query->setParameter('name', implode("%', OR name LIKE '%", $arraySearch));
```

Comment: Edited, sorry about that